# Sum elements from a .csv-file into a file with python

Tags: python, csv, file

I am trying to use Python as a part of my uni education, and have come across a problem with a CSV-file which I hope someone can help me to solve.

The file consists of traffic data for several years, divided by quarters, it looks sort of like this (without the header):

```
2013;kvartal 1;10202;3;8;23\
2013;kvartal 2;10231;3;8;22\
2013;kvartal 3;8736;2;7;21\
2013;kvartal 4;11263;3;8;24\
2014;kvartal 1;9310;2;8;23\
2014;kvartal 2;12643;3;10;25\
2014;kvartal 3;12852;3;9;24\
2014;kvartal 4;8872;2;7;19
```

What I want to do is to sum the quarters into a new list, so that each column for each year is summed. I would like the new list to look something like this:

```
2013 - (the sum for column 3 for year 2013) - (the sum for column 4 for year 2013) - etc.
```

And so on for the rest of the years.

To summarize I would like to sum all the quarters into single years. I've managed to convert the CSV-file into a list, but all the elements are string, and thus I can't seem to sum them.

Does anyone have a good way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using [Python Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html). It's much easier with that. You have to just read the csv file to a panda dataframe and then just find the column sum for those values. Probably would be 2 lines of code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop on the values stored in the list and convert each one into the int using below:

```
    listnew=[]
    for i in list:
        listnew.append(int(i))
    print(sum(listnew))
```

try this out